# pytorch.detach() nicking two rows of pixels

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train Nazeris EdgeConnect (https://github.com/knazeri/edge-connect). The network processes corrupted images to be inpainted at hole positions.
I succeeded training the network few days ago but then somehow my environment got damaged and I had to rebuild it. I have to admit that I my knowledge of conda environments is far from proficient and that successful deployment of these happens to me out of pure luck.

My problem:

somewhere in the model.py class I find the `process()` method, which starts like this:

```
 def process(self, images, edges, masks):
        self.iteration += 1


        # zero optimizers
        self.gen_optimizer.zero_grad()
        self.dis_optimizer.zero_grad()


        # process outputs
        outputs = self(images, edges, masks)
        gen_loss = 0
        dis_loss = 0


        # discriminator loss
        dis_input_real = torch.cat((images, edges), dim=1)
        dis_input_fake = torch.cat((images, outputs.detach()), dim=1)
```

and the error occurs right there in the last row:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 2, in <module>
    main(mode=1)
  File "/path/edge-connect/main.py", line 56, in main
    model.train()
  File "/path/edge-connect/src/edge_connect.py", line 110, in train
    outputs, gen_loss, dis_loss, logs = self.edge_model.process(images_gray, edges, masks)
  File "/path/edge-connect/src/models.py", line 104, in process
    dis_input_fake = torch.cat((images, outputs.detach()), dim=1)
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Got 854 and 852 in dimension 3 (The offending index is 1)
```

So all variables (images, edges, masks) given to process() have the dimension of 480x854 (I verified this). They then get attached (?) at `outputs = self(images, edges, masks)`. Eventually they get detached at the very last line and happened to **have shrunk by two pixels.** `Got 854 and 852 in dimension 3`

I don't really understand which line of code could have caused this bug. I assume that it goes back to deprecated libraries e.g pytorch which could have changed since the functioning run a few days ago.

Where should I start debugging this issue? Has anyone an idea which line of code caused two width-pixels to disappear? what does `self(images, edges, masks)` do?

Comment: since you're asking about this piece as an aside, I'll just comment. -- if `foo` is an instance of some class, then `foo(whatever)` ends up calling the `foo.__call__()` method (with whatever given arguments). the class would contain an explicit implementation of that method, e.g. `def __call__(self, whatever): ...`

Comment: This seems unrelated to detach. More than likely there's some randomness in the way your examples are sampled and there's a shape mismatch in some of your examples that you've been unlucky enough to find with `detach()`.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Exactly! I suppose there is a __call__ function somewhere in the model but it is not. [model.py](https://github.com/knazeri/edge-connect/blob/master/src/models.py)

Comment: all those classes are derived from other classes. it's probably in the respective superclass or even higher.

Comment: okay. Turns out that the self() function calls the modules `forward()` function. In this `forward()` function the scripts performs some 2D-Convolution and messes up the original size due to incorrect padding.

Thank you folks anyway :)